# xlsxwriter adding a second df in a new worksheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have df1 and df2 and would like to generate an excel workbook that has each df in a sheet using `Xlsxwriter`

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
    
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
    
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
    
    workbook  = writer.book

    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    
    worksheet2 = writer.sheets['Sheet2']
    
    writer.save()

    writer.close
```

I also tried to add another sheet using: `worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet2')`

But did not work, searched a bit but nothing seems to solve it!

what am i missing here?

Comment: @Barrank'a answer is the way to go. It aligns with the recommendation in XlsxWriter docs on [Handling multiple Pandas Dataframes](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#handling-multiple-pandas-dataframes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use an [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('path/to/my/file.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2')
```

At least, that's the way I do it .

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Notice a few things: 1. Using an `ExcelWriter` within a context manager saves you from the burden of manually closing it.  2. The writer engine (if you really need to specify it) should be passed as an argument to `ExcelWriter`. [Check the documentation for more info](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html).

Answer (score 1):

Got it working for the format I need with `XlsxWriter` :
This way you can add more sheets **individually** and format them as in [XlsxWriter documentations](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#handling-multiple-pandas-dataframes)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

#df1
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')

#df2
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.

workbook  = writer.book

#worksheet1

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Sheet1 formatting options
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 50)

#worksheet2

worksheet2 = writer.sheets['Sheet2']

# Sheet2  formatting options
worksheet2.set_column('A:A', 50)

# Saving

writer.save()

writer.close()
```